# Delete documents with a missing field in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to delete documents not having a specific field in elastic search. I tried combination of must_not and exists but its giving documents in which the field is there but its null.But i want the docs in which the field is not present at all.

Comment: Can you provide the queries that you tried?

Comment: @alkis This is the query I used:
`"query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must_not":{
      "exists": {
            "field": "USR_EMAIL"
         }
      }
   }
}`